# How to make a HTML5 font lighter when fontWeight doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, css, html, fonts

[Google's Oswald font](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Oswald) seems to ignore the `fontWeight` CSS property. It's very bold.

How to make it lighter?

Comment: You just have to include all the fonts (book, normal and bold), from google and set the weight as number.

Comment: You may have downloaded the `bold` version of that font. You need to include all three (`bold`, `normal`, `italic`)

Comment: @Jashwant how exactly do I get the other fonts? I just linked http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=oswald

Comment: Why would you like to delete a valid question? Sorry but your edit may be classed as vandalism. Remember that all content submitted to StackExchange is licensed under CC. If you really want this deleted, flag it and type in a good reason in the "other" field.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the contents on those images are private. Please do NOT back it up again. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonjour,
It might be the way you link the font style sheet. it works for me:
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/xEdoC

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

```
font-family:Oswald;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the font-weight settings by changing the value from 100-900. There are also other options like `lighter` but I guess it depends on what you are looking for.

More information here: [font-weight CSS|MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)

However I'm not sure how it applies to that font specifically, especially if you say its just straight out ignoring it.

You can also consider changing the `opacity` value via CSS?

Comment: Not exactly what I asked, but thanks for the opacity suggestion, it's beautiful.